# how can i transfet vuejs project source from vuejs linux to vuejs windows

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

how can i transfet or move vue3 files from linux to new vuejs project in windows

i try copy and passt the folder and i get somme error
i have also create new project in windows and copy only the src file and this make somme error

so i need a method the if it existe like (export to.. or compress) ...

this is the errors

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/SearchBar.vue?vue&type=template&id=0eca37cb&scoped=true:133:90)
at Proxy.renderFnWithContext (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:839:13)
at Proxy.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:2123:54)
at renderComponentRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:887:38)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5064:46)
at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:216:19)
at instance.update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5161:51)
at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5169:5)
at mountComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4983:5)
at processComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4948:9)
ERROR
Request failed with status code 404
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)
at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:106:66)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's no "method". The project is transferred somehow, directly or through git. It shouldn't include node_modules because it may be platform dependent. The rest totally depends on your case, which is unknown

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks it help me a lot the probleme was in the node_modules folder